# SQL returning invalid results when comparing against 2 date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server

As mentioned in the subject line, SQL is returning results which are not within the specific date range, here is my SQL snipped below:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
    ,@EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2017-03-04 00:50:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2017-03-05 01:30:00.000

SELECT * FROM table (NOLOCK) WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Partial Results

```
CreatedOn
2017-03-04 04:59:57.010
2017-03-04 17:39:50.460
2017-03-04 05:28:22.610
2017-03-04 20:54:39.257
2017-03-04 17:33:19.107
```

Comment: I only see one date range in your question.  How is it not working?

Comment: Results seems to be ok. Whats the issue?

Comment: can you give us, your expected vs actual results?

Comment: Regardless of what the real issue here might be, be aware that "Specifying table hints without using the WITH keyword" is deprecated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx.

Comment: Hi All thanks for all your comments and answers, I'll probably go through all the answers this weekend and provide more detail if the suggested answers are not what I was looking for.

@dean thanks for the list of deprecated features in MS SQL, and I just wanted to clarify what you meant, did you mean I need to do this `SELECT * FROM table WITH (NOLOCK)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below query and also check your CreatedOn data type as DATETIME OR  
VARCHAR

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME,@EndDate DATETIME

SET @StartDate = '2017-03-04 00:50:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2017-03-05 01:30:00.000

SELECT * FROM table (NOLOCK) 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,CreatedOn,@StartDate) <= 0 AND 
      DATEDIFF(DAY,CreatedOn,@EndDate) >= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, there is no way you get different results for the **given CreatedOn test data**. You need to post actual results vs expected results if you still have problem.

Here is the script I tested and it always prints `Yes` (as the date is in range)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2017-03-04 00:50:00.000',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '2017-03-05 01:30:00.000'

DECLARE @CreatedOn TABLE 
(
    id INT IDENTITY,
    CreatedOn DATETIME
)
INSERT @CreatedOn (CreatedOn)
VALUES  ('2017-03-04 04:59:57.010'),
        ('2017-03-04 17:39:50.460'),
        ('2017-03-04 05:28:22.610'),
        ('2017-03-04 20:54:39.257'),
        ('2017-03-04 17:33:19.107'),

DECLARE @index INT = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @CreatedOn)
DECLARE @testDate DATETIME

WHILE @index >= 1
BEGIN

    SELECT
        @testDate = CreatedOn
    FROM @CreatedOn
    WHERE id = @index

    IF @testDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
        PRINT CAST(@testDate AS VARCHAR) + ' Yes'
    ELSE
        PRINT CAST(@testDate AS VARCHAR) + ' No'

    SET @index = @index - 1
END
```

However the DateTime values are region dependent. If you are having the `CreatedOn` variable/field values in `YYYYMMDD` or `YYYY-MM-DD` format, they are language independent.

You might only get different results if you are using a different format. For example if you are trying to validate the date range for `'04.03.2017 18:00'`, it will fail as it will be interpreted as March 4th 2017 in English regional settings.

Here is a small test script.

```
SET LANGUAGE 'German'
DECLARE @testDateRegion DATETIME = '04.03.2017 15:24'
PRINT CAST(@testDateRegion AS VARCHAR)
GO

SET LANGUAGE 'English'
DECLARE @testDateRegion DATETIME = '04.03.2017 15:24'
PRINT CAST(@testDateRegion AS VARCHAR)
```

and the output is,

```
Die Spracheneinstellung wurde auf Deutsch geändert.
Mär  4 2017  3:24PM
Changed language setting to us_english.
Apr  3 2017  3:24PM
```